# Why can't my genetic algorithm design anything more than a low pass filter?

Tags: filter, signal-processing, genetic-algorithm

I'm developing a genetic algorithm to design an IIR filter that matches a guitar amplifier frequency response. The algorithm works great for low pass filters, however it cannot design a filter that attenuates low frequencies.

This is one example of a frequency response of a filter it produced:

[Frequency response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITfts.png)

It's converging really nicely on the high frequencies, but the low frequency response is just flat as always. If it's a low pass I'm modelling, the algorithm works perfectly.
Can it be related to my search space definition? I've set my coefficients' limits to:
0<k<1; -2<b1<2; 0<b2<1; -2<a1<2; 0<a2<1

The coefficients are equivalent to the ones in this expression:
[Transfer function expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukG1j.png)

Comment: It's pretty accurate from 4000Hz up to 16000Hz.  That's most of the frequency range... if you use a linear instead of logarithmic frequency axis.  Does your fitness function know that you're using a log frequency axis?

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function you specify is a biquadratic filter. The coefficients you are using are all real. As the coefficients are real, the zeros (b1 and b2) and the poles (a1 and a2) are all placed at 0 Hz or fs/2 Hz (Nyquist). As you have zeros and poles at DC or Nyquist, you can't produce anything but a low pass or high pass filter, however you can generate a low pass filters which is very broad (low Q, as per your image) or a very sharp Q. The same Q tuning is possible for high pass filters as well. To specify a bandpass filter (or notched bandpass filter), you need to be able to shift your poles and zeros off the real axis and I will tell you how to do that in this answer.

For clarity, here is the biquadratic filter with an overall system gain (k) and roots b_1, b_2, a_1 and a_2. The numerator roots are zeros and the denominator roots are poles :

```
h = k (1 + b_1 z^-1) (1 + b_2 z^-1)
      -----------------------------
      (1 + a_1 z^-1) (1 + a_2 z^-1)
```

An IIR filter with zeros and poles all placed at 0 Hz (on the real axis) is by definition a low pass filter or a high pass filter but can not be a bandpass filter. The reason for this is that the poles can tune to DC (real poles > 0) or Nyquist frequencies (real poles < 0).

In order to generate arbitrary biquadratic filters, you should allow your poles and zeros to be either real or complex conjugates. For bandpass filters you will need to use complex conjugate poles and complex conjugate zeros to be able to notch out the bandpass nature to some degree. In the complex conjugate case, the filters are specified as follows :

- a1 = conj(a2) = a exp(+- j w_a)
- b1 = conj(b2) = b exp(+- j w_b)

where j is the suare root of -1, the amplitudes of the roots are a and b and for stability b<1. The frequencies where the poles and zeros are placed are 0 < w < pi. Of course when w=0 or w=pi, you are generating real poles or zeros which is a limited version of what you had before and these poles aren't able to generate filters of a bandpass nature.

You system gain (k) is arbitrary and scaled to suit your needs.